# Docker sqlite + Spring Boot

Tags: java, sqlite, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a working Spring Boot application with sqlite. When I am trying to create a container I get the exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [clients]
```

It seems that the container can't access the database file.

File structure is

[image]

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD project-app.jar project-app.jar
ADD mydb.db mydb.db
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","project-app.jar"]
EXPOSE 8082
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    project-app:
      build: ./
      image: project-app:1.0
      restart: always
      container_name: project-app
      ports:
        - 8082:8082
      volumes: 
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      network_mode: bridge
```

I tried adding the sqlite like a container, I also tried replicate MySQL configuration on `docker-compose.yml` but still got the same exception.

Edit: After exploring the container it seems that the database file is present `mydb.db` but it's empty, that means Dockerfile doesn't copy the database.

```
    4 drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     4096 Sep  6 18:27 .
    4 drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     4096 Sep  6 18:27 ..
    0 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root root        0 Sep  6 18:27 .dockerenv
    4 drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     4096 Aug 14 11:23 bin
    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Mar 28 09:12 boot
    0 drwxr-xr-x   5 root root      340 Sep  6 18:57 dev
    4 drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     4096 Sep  6 18:27 etc
    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Mar 28 09:12 home
    4 drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     4096 Aug 12 00:00 lib
    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Aug 12 00:00 lib64
    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Aug 12 00:00 media
    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Aug 12 00:00 mnt
    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Aug 12 00:00 opt
    0 dr-xr-xr-x 145 root root        0 Sep  6 18:57 proc
    4 drwx------   1 root root     4096 Aug 14 11:25 root
    4 drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     4096 Sep  6 18:27 run
    4 drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     4096 Aug 14 06:24 sbin
46260 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 47367833 Sep  6 17:02 project-app.jar
    0 -rw-r--r--   1 root root        0 Sep  6 18:27 mydb.db
    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Aug 12 00:00 srv
    0 dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root        0 Sep  6 18:57 sys
    4 drwxrwxrwt   1 root root     4096 Sep  6 18:57 tmp
    4 drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     4096 Aug 12 00:00 usr
    4 drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     4096 Aug 12 00:00 var
```

Comment: 1. try COPY instead of ADD 2. Use `privileged` flag to give root permission.

Comment: Also check the permissions of your `mydb.db` in your host machine

Comment: @Rash It worked, you can write it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `ADD` is a special docker command used for URLs and tar files. Most of the time it would just do what `COPY` does, but `COPY` is preferred when you don't need the magic of `ADD`. So try if replacing `ADD` with `COPY` works.
2. Check if using the `privileged` flag fixes the issue. The `--privileged` flag gives all capabilities to the container, like limitations enforced by the cgroup controller. The container can then do almost everything that the host can do.
3. Check the permission of `mydb.db` in your host machine. If docker engine won't have proper permissions, it would have trouble copying the file to the docker container.

Comment: You only need `--privileged` if your container needs to be able to do things like reboot the host system, which is to say, almost never.  If the container process runs as user ID 0 then it has root privileges, for filesystem-access purposes.

Comment: I agree. I almost never use privileged flag, or recommend it, unless doing docker-in-docker type of setup.